# Building shared libraries with cmake with option -Wl,--no-undefined

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create a ndk library using android-cmake.

My target here is a shared library and build fails because of option

```
-Wl,--no-undefined
```

As the targets refers symbols from another library.

Is there a way to the missing library to the command

```
add_library(foo SHARED ${sources})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build by changing cmake variable

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -L<path to library> -lfoo")
```